# Count entries in a list depending from the current user

Tags: 2013, javascript, user

I have a list (Teamsites) in SP 2013 onPrem with a people picker field (Owner).

Now I want show a counter of all list entries where the current user is standing in the Owner-Field.

How i can realized it in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

User REST API to get the List Items where Owner=CurrentUser. Hope you are aware how to call Rest API in Javascript code.if not please see [here](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/04/09/how-to-query-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-and-javascript.aspx)

using below REST API you will be able to get the filtered List Item

```
https://[Your SharePoint URL]/_api/web/lists/YourList/items?$select=Title&$expand=FieldValuesAsText/Owner&$filter=Owner eq 1
```

here in code `Owner eq 1`  "1" is the current user ID which you can get using `_spPageContextInfo.userId` in Javascript code.

Once you get the result from rest ,get the count in Success method using below code
`data.d.results.length`

Comment: It isn't working. I forgot to say that the owen-field is a multiple choice field.